# Skim and Aquamacs: backward search does not work anymore

Tags: auctex, forward-inverse-search, aquamacs

I've set up pdf syncing between Aquamacs and Skim,

```
    (setq server-use-tcp t)
(server-start)

(custom-set-variables
 '(LaTeX-command "latex -synctex=1")
 '(TeX-view-program-list (quote (("Skim" "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline %n %o %b") ("Preview" "open -a Preview.app %o"))))
)

(setq TeX-source-correlate-method 'synctex)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-source-correlate-mode)
```

Forward search and pdf syncing work fine, and backward searching was working yesterday. However, today, when I clicked <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ClICK</kbd> in Skim, it does not do backward searching anymore. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: You have to select Aquamacs in the preferences for Skim

Comment: Yes Aquamacs is selected in Skim preferences. It was working fine yesterday, today all of a sudden it stopped working. Very strange.

Comment: I just found out that in Aquamacs, CMD+SHIFT+CLICK also does forward search, but usually this is done by C-c C-v, right? Is something going wrong here?

Comment: Aquamacs has many key combos similar to the “usual” Mac OS X style (CMD-O, CMD-S, and so on). The developers chose to add also CMD+SHIFT+CLICK for the forward search, just because Skim uses the same combo for backward search.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I solved the problem by using custom preferences in Skim.

I changed the command to:

```
/Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient
```

And now the backward search works again!

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: That was very helpful. I simply set the command to the output of the terminal command `which emacsclient`, in my case `/usr/local/bin/emacsclient`.